# Angular 2 V/S Angular js V/S React js v/s Typescript

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, typescript, angular

I am a simple and newbie web developer. I am going to create a simple website for my own use.

As a newbie web developer i know only very few concepts of JavaScript and jQuery.

For building my website i thought let's build with some new concepts.

So when i started searching i got to know lots of new libraries like AngularJS, Angular 2, TypeScript, React.js and Node.js. whewww...

So I want to ask a simple question, what are all these libraries?

Is there any difference between Angular 2 [Angular Connect](https://angular.io/) AngularJS [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)?

I know that [React.js](https://facebook.github.io/react/) is created by Facebook and [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) is created by Google.

**I don't want to create the comparison between all this libraries. But want to understand all this concepts in single page with clear answer.**

As a web developer I just want to know what all this things are?

Please just help me to make all this Terms simple. **And please let me know what each library provides?**

Answer (score 7):

> Angular 2 V/S Angular js V/S React js v/s Typescript

First angular 2 vs. angular 1

- Angular 2 : its the next version of angular ... currently under active development. It is *being* rewritten in TypeScript https://angular.io/
- Angular 1 : Its the current version of angular : https://angularjs.org/

Now angular vs. react

- Angular is a full featured framework (e.g. http routing is baked in). React is just the *view* with people providing the other libraries (like http routing).

Finally TypeScript : Its just a programming language that transpiles to JavaScript and can therefore be used with any of these frameworks.

Comment: Sorry for such comment. But Angular 2 is handled by completely different community / organization or handled by same community may be google?

Comment: Angular is by Google, React by Facebook

Comment: Don't be sorry, Angular <1 and 2 both are supported by Google only, its just that Angular 2 is now based on Typescript which is developed by Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is not a library, it's a language that compiles to Javascript, permits **static typing**, and some other stuff like writing ES6 and  compiling it to ES5.

An important thing of Typescript is that any Javascript code is valid Typescript code. It's a superset of JS, that means that it just adds features to JS, but keeps all of it compatible.

It's compatible with each of the three libraries.